# lua - How do I access a variable in a elseif statement

Tags: lua

```
--If STATEMENT
        elseif line:match("^if") then
            local v, e, c, v2 = line:match("^if (.+) = (.+) > (.+) > (.+)")
                if vars[v] == e then
                    if c == "print" then
                        print(v2)
                    elseif c == "run" then
                        if funcs[v2] then
                            if funcs[v2] == "print" then
                                print("hi")
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end

        --Functions
        elseif line:match("^func") then
            local n, c, o = line:match("^func (.+) > (.+) > (.+)")
            funcs[n] = c
        end
```

This code is used for a programming language im developing and im having troubles with running functions

While that code up there works, there is one problem...
I want to print off the var "o" set in the elseif statement under "--Functions", it is detecting that i want to print something in the function but i just dont know how to access the variable o in a different elseif statement, because in the "--If statement" area it is looking to see if the code in the file looks similar to this `if var = 1 > run > functionname`  and the code in the file for a function looks like this `func functionname > print > Hello` which works and for dev purposes I made it print off "hi" so it is detecting in the function that i want to print but, in the section ("--function") i have a variable called o, which is what is supposed to be printed off, I hope i explaned well and I hope you guys understand, and thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Ok I fixed it my self after I posted this by messing around

so I basically create a variable called fCom (Function Command)
then in the "--Functions" section I set fCom to equal o and I have made multiple functions to test it out and it does work

This is the new code:

```
--If STATEMENT
        elseif line:match("^if") then
            local v, e, c, v2 = line:match("^if (.+) = (.+) > (.+) > (.+)")
                if vars[v] == e then
                    if c == "print" then
                        print(v2)
                    elseif c == "run" then
                        if funcs[v2] then
                            if funcs[v2] == "print" then
                                --[[ EDITED --]] print(fCom)
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end

        --Functions
        elseif line:match("^func") then
            local n, c, o = line:match("^func (.+) > (.+) > (.+)")
            funcs[n] = c
            --[[ EDITED --]]
            fCom = o
        end
```